# Question on interpreter.cpp in Bitcoin core - set_success method

Tags: bitcoin-core

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/interpreter.cpp

Line 22 => Where is declare "ScriptError" ? What does the "*" mean ?

```
           "inline bool set_success(ScriptError* ret)"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The enum `ScriptError` is defined in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script_error.h, and the `*` means that `set_success` requires you to pass a pointer to an enum value rather than the enum value itself.

I have to tell you, however, that if you are asking questions like "What does the "*" mean?", then you are going to have a hard time understanding C++ code.  I highly recommend doing some tutorials on C++ programming before going any further.

Comment: I  know about pointers I was just disturbed by the fact that it is wrote "ScriptError*" and not "*ScriptError"

Comment: `*ScriptError` would mean dereferencing a variable named "ScriptError".  For example, see line 25 interpreter.cpp, where `ret` is dereferenced in order to assign a new value.  I think you are thinking of writing `set_success(ScriptError* ret)` like `set_success(ScriptError *ret)`, instead.  In C++, both mean the same thing.

Comment: Do you understand what is happening line 167 ?

Comment: std::vector<unsigned char> vchSigCopy(vchSig.begin(), vchSig.begin() + vchSig.size() - 1);

Comment: It's creating a copy of `vchSig` called `vchSigCopy`.  However, it's neither possible nor appropriate for me to teach you C++ in the comments.  Some of these questions you've been asking are very fundamental concepts in C++.  You really need to take some time to learn the language if you want to understand Bitcoin's code.